# How to assign default parameters to an object created from a file that does not have those parameters?

Tags: java, class, object, parameters

Information from file: Shape, radius/height/width, color, filled

```
CIRCLE, 1, blue, true
RECTANGLE, 1, 2, blue, true
RECTANGLE, 10, 2, red, true
CIRCLE, 2, green
RECTANGLE
CIRCLE
```

Program: Once it reaches the 4th line where it is missing the parameter true/false, the program doesn't assign it the default values from the other classes. How do I assign the default parameters to that newly created object when there are no parameters specified in the file?

Default values are: color = white, filled = false, radius = 1, height = 1, width = 1.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(
                "C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/GeometricObjectsData.txt"));

        ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(", ");
            if (tokens[0].equals("CIRCLE")) {
                Circle c = new Circle();
                float radius = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
                c.setRadius(radius);
                String color = String.valueOf(tokens[2]);
                c.setColor(color);
                Boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(tokens[3]);
                c.setFilled(filled);
                c.getArea();
                list.add(c);
                System.out.println(c.toString());
            } else if (tokens[0].equals("RECTANGLE")) {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                float height = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                r.setHeight(height);
                float width = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                r.setWidth(width);
                String color = String.valueOf(tokens[3]);
                r.setColor(color);
                Boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(tokens[4]);
                r.setFilled(filled);
                r.getArea();
                list.add(r);
                System.out.println(r.toString());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use line.split() and there are not enough parameters in the files, you will not have tokens[1],tokens[2] and so on.

So you have to check the length of the tokens array to see if you have enough parameters. If not, assign the default value. You can assign the default value first and then check the condition. For example:

```
float radius = 1.0F;
if (tokens.length >= 2) {
    radius = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the default values I have assigned in the other classes instead of just creating a new default radius? Like I have the default color/filled in the GeometricObject class and radius in the Circle class and height/width in the Rectangle class.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean having default values in the class itself? Of course you can. You can set it in the class constructor or an initializer in the class. But you will still need to have the `if` statement that I have written in order to assign the value from tokens only when a value exists.

Comment: I have 3 other classes called GeometricObject, Circle, and Rectangle and within those classes I have constructors that assign default values to an object. So how would I call upon those objects for the default values rather then just defining them again in the main class?

Comment: You create the objects with the constructors. In the Driver, however, you have an if statement like I wrote, but slightly different. If `tokens.length >= 2` you then do both the `parseFloat` and the `setRadius` inside the if block. So if you don't have the necessary parameter, that part will be skipped, and the object will stay with the default values assigned when you created it.